# Wanna try 32 bytes of data to Server but can't do it with AJAX - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I want to send 32 bytes to server (euw.leagueoflegends.com), and get the milliseconds delay. What I've tried so far:

```
var sendDate = (new Date()).getTime();
            var strServer = getCurrentServer();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {},
                datatype: 'jsonp',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://" + strServer + ".leagueoflegends.com",
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
                },
                success: function(){
                var receiveDate = (new Date()).getTime();

                var responseTimeMs = receiveDate - sendDate;
                Materialize.toast('Your ping is ' + responseTimeMs + ' for ' + strServer + ' server.', 4000);
            },
                   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                Materialize.toast('Something wrong happened. Please try again.');
            }
        })
```

But... Even I looked almost all of the questions about this, I still get a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must be in the *response* from the server, it has no meaning when sent in the *request*.  If the server does not reply with access control headers/jsonp you have no access & will need a server side proxy.

Comment: Try a [cors proxy](https://www.crossorigin.me/).

Comment: @mkaatman crossorigin returns : Origin: header is required

Comment: @AlexK. What should I do?

Comment: @mkaatman Alright I read the main page of crossorigin.me, and It says target page doesn't include `Origin` header. Also, it cannot handle Post events. Other alternatives?